# How to use an asyncio loop inside another asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have been trying all kinds of things to be able to use an asyncio loop inside another asyncio loop. Most of the time my test just end in errors, such as:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

My example code below is just the base test I started with, so you can see the basics of what I am trying to do. I tried so many things after this test, it was just too confusing, so I figured I should keep it simple when asking for help. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thank you for your time!

```
import asyncio

async def fetch(data):
    message = 'Hey {}!'.format(data)
    other_data = ['image_a.com', 'image_b.com', 'image_c.com']
    images = sub_run(other_data)
    return {'message' : message, 'images' : images}

async def bound(sem, data):
    async with sem:
        r = await fetch(data)
        return r

async def build(dataset):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(400)

    for data in dataset:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound(sem, data))
        tasks.append(task)

    r = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return r

def run(dataset):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(build(dataset))
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
    return responses

async def sub_fetch(data):
    image = 'https://{}'.format(data)
    return image

async def sub_bound(sem, data):
    async with sem:
        r = await sub_fetch(data)
        return r

async def sub_build(dataset):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(400)

    for data in dataset:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(sub_bound(sem, data))
        tasks.append(task)

    r = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return r

def sub_run(dataset):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(sub_build(dataset))
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
    return responses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Zoe', 'Howard']
    responses = run(dataset)
    print (responses)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Running `loop.run_until_compete` inside a running event loop would block the outer loop, thus defeating the purpose of using asyncio. Because of that, asyncio event loops aren't recursive, and one shouldn't need to run them recursively. (See [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22239) for details.) Instead of creating an inner event loop, `await` a task on the existing one.

In your case, remove `sub_run` and simply replace its usage:

```
images = sub_run(other_data)
```

with:

```
images = await sub_build(other_data)
```

And it will work just fine, running the sub-coroutines and not continuing with the outer coroutine until the inner one is complete, as you likely intended from the sync code.

Comment: That is awesome! I get it now! I can just use the same loop and create more task for that loop. You explained it very clearly, thank you very much.

Comment: Don't we need to change `sub_run()` from sync to async?

Comment: @EmersonXu The idea is to completely get rid of `sub_run`.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes, it's very clear to remove sub_run() in this case. But say if we have many sync function calls inside `run()`, do we need to convert all sync functions to async?

Comment: @EmersonXu Either convert them, or use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to execute legacy blocking code.

Comment: @Tom I feel your pain, having two versions of everything is a well-known problem with colored-function approach to async. It's not unique to Python either, the same problem is shared by Rust, C#, C++, Kotlin, and to some extent JavaScript. Unfortunately fixing this by allowing recursive calls into the event loop doesn't work because async suspension signal doesn't propagate over the sync portions of the call stack. And retrofitting a colorless approach (a la Go) into an existing language with a large extension ecosystem was not a realistic option, either.

Comment: Maybe I just don't get it but: the fugg? Not being able to run a loop inside another loop is actually a design decision? This will break the second someone imports a 3rd party lib that makes use of asyncio in the background.

Comment: @omni It's a [design decision](https://bugs.python.org/issue22239), yes. You can't spin up an asyncio loop _inside_ another asyncio loop, but nothing stops you from running two (or more) of them in different threads. That's what third-party libs that make use of asyncio in the background do, and it works just fine.

Comment: @user4815162342 maybe someone should tell that to _all_ 3rd party lib autors then because at least I ran into issues with multiple of them already. That "design decision" is bad imho since expecting everyone will just follow that "rule" and create and manage threads properly when using asyncio is utopical. Besides I don't really get the point of using asyncio if I create threads for everything anyway and it makes things just way more complex. E.g. if you want to pass data to asyncio in a typical c-p loop you first need threading.queue and then asyncio.queue just to pass data into the loop...

Comment: @omni *maybe someone should tell that to all 3rd party lib autors then because at least I ran into issues with multiple of them already* - I suspect you were using them wrong, but at this point I feel like I'm advocating/defending design decisions made by other people 10 years ago. It's not my intention to do so, I just pointed to to the primary source and attempted to shed light on the "correct" way to do it. If that doesn't work for you, maybe it would actually be a good idea to create an issue on cpython's github and argue your case.

Comment: @user4815162342 I get that, no offense. All I'm saying is that from my exp. with it asyncio in it's current impl. makes things unnecessarily complicated.